# NULL POINTER EXCEPTION in the Widget provider class at first launch of Widget

Tags: android, android-widget

Hi Everyone , 
              I am having some trouble with a NULL POINTER EXCEPTION.I get the error only when I place the widget in the home screen for the first time.Every other time the widget works perfectly.
        The widget has a configuration activity. This activity does not launch,instead the onReceive in the widget provider get called and troughs the NULL POINTER EXCEPTION.
         Can any one provide a good solution to my problem?

I am attaching the code for the configure activity and the widget provider class.

The widget configure class:

```
public class SingleNoteConfigure extends ListActivity  {


private NotesDbAdapter mDbHelper;
int mAppWidgetId = AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID;
public static String ACTION_WIDGET_LIST = "ActionReceiverList";
public static String ACTION_WIDGET_NEW = "ActionReceiverNew";



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //set the result to canceled to allow the user
    //to change their mind mid widget configure
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
    Log.d("MYTAG", "in the onCreate of of the widget configure");

    //set the layout file for the widget configure
    setContentView(R.layout.notes_list_config);

    //using the action bar title for user instruction
    setTitle("Select note to display on the wodget");

    // Find the widget id from the intent. 
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(
                AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }
    Log.d("MYTAG", "in the onCreate");
    //stuff to get the database to open
    mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();

    //call the method that fills the list view
    fillData();

}

 @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        Cursor note = mDbHelper.fetchNote(id);
        startManagingCursor(note);
        String title = note.getString(note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE));
        String text = note.getString(note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY));



        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.singlenote_widget);
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this); 
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(mAppWidgetId, views);    



        Log.d("MYTAG", "in the onListItemClick....");

        loadData(title, text, id);//here id is the row id of the selection;it is returned by the onListItemSelect 

        Intent resultValue = new Intent();
        resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);            
        setResult(RESULT_OK,resultValue);   
        finish();
 }



 void loadData(String title, String text, Long Id) {

    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this); 
    Log.d("MYTAG", "in the load data....");
    SingleNote.updateWidget(this, appWidgetManager, mAppWidgetId, title, text);
    NotesDbAdapter.updateWidgetId(mAppWidgetId,Id);

}

private void fillData() {
    Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(notesCursor);
    Log.d("MYTAG", "in the fill data  of the widget configure");
    // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (TITLE and DATE)
    String[] from = new String[]{NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE,NotesDbAdapter.KEY_DATE};


    // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (title and date)
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.title,R.id.date};


    // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
    SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row1, notesCursor, from, to);

    setListAdapter(notes);


}  
}
```

The widget provide class:

```
public class SingleNote extends AppWidgetProvider {

public static String UPDATE_ACTION = "ActionUpdateSinglenoteWidget";

private static NotesDbAdapter mDbHelper;



public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];            

        Log.d("MYTAG", "in the onUpdate");

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Notepadv3.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.singlenote_widget);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.single_note_text, pendingIntent);  

        // Push update for this widget to the home screen

        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, SingleNote.class);
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, views);

    }
}

@Override 
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
    Log.d("MYTAG", "in the onReceive....");
        String action = intent.getAction(); 
        Log.d("MYTAG", "in the onReceive....line 2");
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); 
        Log.d("MYTAG", "in the onReceive....after bundle");//THis gets in the log 
        String title = extras.getString("title");
        Log.d("MYTAG", "in the onReceive....after title");//Non of the other log entry's
                                                          // make it in 
        String text = extras.getString("body");
        Log.d("MYTAG", "in the onReceive....after text");
        Log.d("MYTAG", "@ the point of int");
        int id = extras.getInt("widget_id");

        Log.d("MYTAG", action+ title + text + id);

        if (action != null && action.equals(UPDATE_ACTION)) { 
            final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context); 

            if (id > 0)
            {
                updateWidget(context, appWidgetManager, id ,title ,text);
            }
            else {
                return;

            }
    } 

    else { 
            super.onReceive(context, intent); 
    } 


}

static void updateWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId, String title, String text){

    Log.d("MYTAG", "in the updatewidget method in the siglenote widget....");
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.singlenote_widget);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.single_note_title, title);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.single_note_text, text);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);



}
}
```

As you can see I have log entries all over the place and I have commented at the point where the Log entries end.

this method is in one of the activities , and I call it to update my widget as required.
I have a "if(!null)" at the end of the method just so that is don't get the NULL POINTER EXCEPTION , but it doesn't seem to be helping

```
private void updateWidget() { 
    Cursor note = mDbHelper.fetchWidgetId(mRowId);
    startManagingCursor(note);
    Log.d("MYTAG", "in the updatewidget method in edit note");
    int id = note.getInt(note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_WIDGET_ID));//here id is the widget id we get out of the database
    Intent i = new Intent(this, SingleNote.class); 
    i.setAction(SingleNote.UPDATE_ACTION); 
    i.putExtra("title", mTitleText.getText().toString());
    i.putExtra("body", mBodyText.getText().toString());
    i.putExtra("widget_id",id);
    String title = mTitleText.getText().toString();
    //String body =  mBodyText.getText().toString();
    if(title != null){ 
    sendBroadcast(i); 
    }
```

EDIT the stack trace:

```
    07-12 04:08:36.473: E/STACKTRACE_TAG(2615): STACKTRACE
    07-12 04:08:36.483: E/STACKTRACE_TAG(2615): java.lang.NullPointerException
    07-12 04:08:36.483: E/STACKTRACE_TAG(2615):     at drkstr.yan.SingleNote.onReceive(SingleNote.java:58)
    07-12 04:08:36.483: E/STACKTRACE_TAG(2615):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1994)
    07-12 04:08:36.483: E/STACKTRACE_TAG(2615):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:132)
    07-12 04:08:36.483: E/STACKTRACE_TAG(2615):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1093)
    07-12 04:08:36.483: E/STACKTRACE_TAG(2615):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    07-12 04:08:36.483: E/STACKTRACE_TAG(2615):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
    07-12 04:08:36.483: E/STACKTRACE_TAG(2615):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
    07-12 04:08:36.483: E/STACKTRACE_TAG(2615):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-12 04:08:36.483: E/STACKTRACE_TAG(2615):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    07-12 04:08:36.483: E/STACKTRACE_TAG(2615):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    07-12 04:08:36.483: E/STACKTRACE_TAG(2615):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    07-12 04:08:36.483: E/STACKTRACE_TAG(2615):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    07-12 04:08:45.483: E/STACKTRACE_TAG(2615): STACKTRACE
    07-12 04:08:45.483: E/STACKTRACE_TAG(2615): java.lang.NullPointerException
    07-12 04:08:45.483: E/STACKTRACE_TAG(2615):     at drkstr.yan.SingleNote.onReceive(SingleNote.java:58)
    07-12 04:08:45.483: E/STACKTRACE_TAG(2615):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1994)
    07-12 04:08:45.483: E/STACKTRACE_TAG(2615):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:132)
    07-12 04:08:45.483: E/STACKTRACE_TAG(2615):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1093)
    07-12 04:08:45.483: E/STACKTRACE_TAG(2615):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    07-12 04:08:45.483: E/STACKTRACE_TAG(2615):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
    07-12 04:08:45.483: E/STACKTRACE_TAG(2615):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
    07-12 04:08:45.483: E/STACKTRACE_TAG(2615):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-12 04:08:45.483: E/STACKTRACE_TAG(2615):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    07-12 04:08:45.483: E/STACKTRACE_TAG(2615):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    07-12 04:08:45.483: E/STACKTRACE_TAG(2615):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    07-12 04:08:45.483: E/STACKTRACE_TAG(2615):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here are my main questions :
  1. Why does this only happen when I am placing the widget for the first time after a fresh    install of the application ?
  2. Why is the onRecieve called before the widget configure ?
  3. And finally how do I solve it.

Thanks for taking the time to read this and for any help that you can give.

Comment: When you are looking for help with an exception you should provide your stack trace

Comment: I totally agree with @jqpubliq we need the stack trace and the log will be helpful...

Comment: just added it in , did not know what a stack trace is till now. Can some one also explain that all of that stuff means ?                     Also a quick note, the widget works fine after I added the           try
    {
     ...
     }
      catch (Exception e)
    {
       Log.e(APP_TAG, "STACKTRACE");
       Log.e(APP_TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
     }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing you should notice is that you have a `NullPointerException` at `SingleNote.java:58`.

Judging from your comments about which statements show up in the log, I'd guess that `extras` is null, which means that there are [no extras in the Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras%28%29). That makes sense if it only happens the first time. Null-check extras before using it.